# Cx_Oracle. using to_date in python

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I want to insert a row into my table, but I am getting an error. Where am I going wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE  person (

  name          VARCHAR(40),
  birthday      DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (name)
  );
```

Now in python I try to insert a person with the following statement...

```
     curs = connection.cursor

     name = input("Name: ")
     birthday = input("Birthdate(yyyy-mm-dd): ")

     insert = """insert into people(name, birthday) values (:name,:birthday)"""

     curs.execute(insert,{'name':name,'to_date(birthday, "yyyy-mm-dd")':birthday})
```

I get the following error:

```
curs.execute(insert,{'name':name,'to_date(birthday, "yyyy-mm-dd")':birthday})
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, I was inserting the date wrong.
My syntax was incorrect and should have been:

```
 curs = connection.cursor

 name = input("Name: ")
 birthday = input("Birthdate(yyyy-mm-dd): ")

 insert = """insert into people(name, birthday) values (:name, to_date(:birthday, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))"""

 curs.execute(insert,{'name':name, 'birthday':birthday})
```